# Differential Equations: Uniqueness and two solutions.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have been stuck with the **theory side** to this question.

If :
$(2t+x)x' = 2t^3 -4t -2x $
With:
 $x(1) = -1$
Then $x(t) = t^2 -2t$ is a continuously differentiable solution to the IVP valid for all t.

> Find another continuously differentiable solution to the IVP , valid fou all t, and **discuss what uniqueness theorem allows two solutions to exist.**

My attempt:

Solving the differential equation I got:
$x(t) = \sqrt{t^4} - 2t $

**Theory:**
Now this describes two curves which are both solutions to the differential equation passing through (1,-1) .
My confusion comes from why two solutions can exist and how to find them.
If I let $x' = \frac{2t^3 -4t-2x}{2t+x} $
And differentiate the right hand side with respect to x the derivative will be continuous at (1,-1) but discontinuous at $(\frac{1}{2} , -1)$ and infinitely many other points.
**Can I then assume that many solutions can exist and if so what theorem/why?**

Comment: $$(2t+x)x' = t^2 (-2 + 2 t) \ne  2t^3 -4t -x = t^2-2 t$$ Are you sure you wrote the problem and / or the solution $x(t)$ correctly?

Comment: @Moo fixed, sorry for the typo, $-2x$ instead of $-x$ in DE

Comment: The square root sign is always positive.  Presumably what you mean to say with $\sqrt{t^4}$ is $\pm t^2$

Comment: @RossMillikan yes but why does this allow two different solutions, or does it?

Comment: @ocallam: Would $x(t) = -t^2 - 2t$ satisfy the IC?

Comment: @Moo No I see now that it would not

Comment: [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(2t%2Bx)x%27%3D2t%5E3-4t-2x) gets solutions $x(t)=\pm \sqrt{c+t^4}-2t$ without the initial condition.  That looks like it comes from solving $((x-2t)^2)'=4t^3$

Comment: @RossMillikan does the initial condition not restrict it to positive? Also if you know of any theorems/ other problems relevant to this it would be very beneficial

Comment: @ocallam: Perhaps see https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/~tyson/existence.pdf and http://home.iitk.ac.in/~sghorai/TEACHING/MTH203/ode5.pdf and http://www.math.colostate.edu/~gerhard/M345/CHP/ch2_7.pdf

Comment: @Moo I have read those and my understanding is that I need a discontinuity around at the point of the partial of RHS or just discontinuity of the RHS, but it is not discontinuous at (1,-1) so I don't understand why there can be two solutions.